# Remote python development with raspberry pi 500MB ram

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, ide, remote-debugging, remote-development

I am trying to use python in a raspberry pi 3a+ that has less than 500MB RAM and finding it very difficult to use any python IDE successfully for remote development.

What I have tried so far:

1. VS Code server: Takes too much ram even without any extensions. I have waited days for installing the python extension to be even installed remotely but without any success. I'm geussing it just crashes the pi and it becomes unresponsive.
2. Visualgdb linux remote python development: I have successfully used visualgdb in embedded c++ projects and I like it very much. But no linting for installed packages.
3. Pycharm: I tried pycharm but ARM development is not supported.

Any other suggestions that might work?

Answer (score -1):

Try downloading the soure python file for each module, then modify the system path (plenty of tutorials online) to make it importable